# How to read gds_result.txt and get data.frame using R

Tags: r

I want to read gds_result.txt from [enter link description here](https://github.com/juancholkovich/GEO_DataSet_Browser/blob/master/gds_result.txt)
using R and get dataframe.
The data.frame have 7 columns. The colnames of data.frame were:

1. title 2. contents 3. Organism 4. Type 5. Platform 6. FTP download 7. DataSet
   How to get?

Answer (score 1):

You could start with this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

txt<-read_lines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juancholkovich/GEO_DataSet_Browser/master/gds_result.txt")

txt %>% as_data_frame() %>% 
  filter(!value=='') %>% 
  mutate(new_group=as.numeric(str_detect(value, "^(\\d*?\\. )")),
         group=cumsum(new_group),
         keyword=str_match(value, "^Organism|^Project|^Type|^FTP|^Sample|^Series|^Source"),
         keyword=ifelse(str_detect(tolower(value), "^dataset|^series|^sample|^platform|related platforms"), "Dataset", keyword),
         keyword=ifelse(str_detect(tolower(value), "accession"), "Accession", keyword),
         keyword=ifelse(new_group==1, "Name", keyword),
         keyword=ifelse(is.na(keyword), "Comment", keyword)
  ) %>% select(-new_group) %>% spread(key=keyword, value=value)
```

There's probably a lot more cleaning to be done, but at least you get some structure to your data.